# Angularjs/Slim framework http put error

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ionic-framework, slim

I'm using ionic framework, trying to update user information with http put method and I get errors every time. I think php slim framework codes have no problem because I tried it from change [this example](http://anjanawijesundara.blogspot.com.cy/2015/04/crud-application-with-angularjs.html)  put method codes with given the following put codes and **slim framework codes work in there**. So I think **Angular js** code has problem. 
Where is the problem? Anyone can help me?
Thanks.

**Slim framework codes:**

```
$app->put('/duzenle/:id',function($id) use ($app){
        $request = $app->request();
        $veri = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $sql = "UPDATE sinav_users SET u_name=:u_name, u_realname=:u_realname, u_email=:u_email WHERE u_id=:u_id";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("u_name", $veri->u_name);
        $stmt->bindParam("u_realname", $veri->u_realname);
        $stmt->bindParam("u_email", $veri->u_email);
        $stmt->bindParam("u_id",  $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $db = null;
                echo json_encode($veri);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }})->name('duzenle');
```

**Angularjs codes:**

```
$scope.duzenle=function(userr){
var url2="http://server_ip/sinav_api/duzenle/"+id;
console.log(url2);
    var promise = $http({method: 'PUT', url: url2, data:userr,  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}});
    promise.success(function (data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
    console.log("ok");
    });
    promise.error(function (data, status) {
    console.log("fail");        
    });
  };
```

**Scope user data from there:**

```
<ion-view style="" title="Duzenle">
<ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="true" padding="true">
    <form style="" class="list" ng-repeat="user in userlist">
        <label style="" class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Gercek isim<font color="red">*</font></span>
            <input placeholder="Old:{{user.u_realname}}"  ng-model="userr.u_realname" type="text" required>
        </label>
        <label style="" class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">E-posta<font color="red">*</font></span>
            <input placeholder="Old:{{user.u_email}}" ng-model="userr.u_email" type="email" required>
        </label>
        <label style="" class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Kullanıcı ismi<font color="red">*</font></span>
            <input placeholder="Old:{{user.u_name}}" ng-model="userr.u_name" type="text" required>
        </label>
        <button style="" class="button button-positive button-block " ng-click="duzenle(userr)">Duzenle</button>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpG8E.png)

Comment: There are any error details available ?

Comment: When try to get error status in console log get **0**

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the console window if you can, including the response from server.

Comment: data null status 0 >[link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YpG8E.png)

Comment: Is the server on same domain? If not prob a CORS issue

Comment: But I was declare `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` in slim api for CORS @danday74. Also When emulate in android the application work it there but when try in `ionic serve` for [desktop browser testing](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html), **put method** not work there.

Answer (score 0):

Put is probably not working because put and post CORS requests make a preflight OPTIONS request first, the purpose of the options request is to ensure that the correct access control allow origin headers are in place

You need to ensure that CORS is allowing methods PUT and POST

There is a header to allow this that must be set on your server

You will prob find if you look at the net tab in your browser that an OPTIONS request is being made and that the PUT is never made because the wrong CORS headers are on your server

Also there is some angular code that will make it work with the OPTIONS preflight request, Google it, this is enough info for you to investigate to fix this.